# Is it possible to identify which client/server TCP sockets are connected to each other in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm wondering if there's a way to determine which client and server sockets are connected to each other in node/JavaScript. Here's a quick example to make it more clear what I mean by `clientSocket` and `serverSocket`.

```
import http from 'http';
import net from 'net';


const port = 4004;
const server = http.createServer(options).listen(port);

let clientSocket;
server.on('connection', (serverSocket) => {
  // Is there any way to identify that `clientSocket` and `serverSocket` are connected?
});

clientSocket = net.connect(port);
```

There's only one client socket and one server socket in this example, but obviously things get more complicated when you're dealing with a large number of connections. Aside from sending data through the connections, is there any way to determine that which sockets are connected to each other?

Comment: I assume you mean on the same machine? And which target OS?

Comment: I mean the same machine, and even the same node process on the machine. The target OS is Linux.

Comment: Why is a single process using TCP to talk to itself? That seems very inefficient...

Comment: I'm trying to use `https.Server` to test an SSL client implementation.

Comment: For testing makes sense. Although then you can also track the relationships yourself manually.

Comment: Is it only possible by opening the connections sequentially though (or running multiple servers on different ports)?

Comment: You can get access to that data through the Linux kernel, but the solution won't be portable. I think 'netstat' can help you. I'm not on a Linux machine right now to test it to give a more specific answer at the moment. Anything along these lines will be cumbersome, though.